# Is there a vendor who will always have life gems in stock?

Tags: dark-souls-2

This game is stupidly fun but also stupidly hard. Having only one Estus Flask is really killing me here. I keep burning through all the life gems I have and then die and since I don't get them back this game just gets harder and harder.

Are there any merchants near a bonfire that will always have life gems in stock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a merchant near a bonfire in the Forest of Giants who will sell lifegems in limited supply. After talking to her a few times, and defeating the boss of the forest, she'll move to Majula, at which point her supply of lifegems will become infinite. You'll know you've talked to her enough because she'll talk about it being time for her to move on.

However, it seems your real problem is that you need more Estus Flasks. You're able to get more by finding Estus Flask Shards and giving them to the Emerald Herald in Majula. There are three Estus Shards you can find fairly early on.

The first can be found inside the well by the mansion in Majula. Just knock over the rock down the well and an Estus Flask Shard will appear.

A second one can be find in a room above the second bonfire in the Forest of Fallen Giants. The door will say it's locked, but you can actually break it open if you just attack it.

Finally, you can find another Estus Flask Shard inside the mansion. You'll get the key from Cale the Cartographer inside the Forest of Fallen Giants. You'll find him shortly after the second bonfire inside the Forest of Fallen Giants. Just go down the ladder next to the bonfire, and when you get to the area with the large tree drop down to the area below. You'll then find him inside of a cave on the side opposite where you came in.  Just keep talking to him and he'll eventually give you the key to his mansion.

Answer (score 4):

After a certain point in the game, the NPC

> Merchant Hag Melentia (sp?)

moves to Majula, and later still they start selling Lifegems with no buy limit. I'm not sure if the trigger for the move is hit by buying items from the NPC

> although this does give you a ring if you are a good enough customer and then talk to her

or from progressing through the game a certain amount. However, it seems you have to talk to the NPC before they will move, regardless.